# Is there a way to read GET http ajax requests with linux?

Tags: ajax, linux, http, get

Under Windows I am using Firefox and `Live HTTP Headers` - it works like a charm

I am reading this site : http://www.modlitwawdrodze.pl/home/

what I need is this request

```
GET /?eID=tx_mnmysql2json_Table&atribute[action]=getTable&atribute[tableName]=mwd_prayers&atribute[limit]=14&atribute[orderBy]=date_start%20asc&atribute[fields]=uid,title,sigla,period_of_liturgical,date_start,audio_file,audio_file_text&atribute[where]=pid=23%20AND%20deleted=0%20AND%20publish=1%20AND%20date_start%3E=1397340000%20AND%20date_start%3C1398549600
```

I want to read this request with Linux; do you know any script or application that can be run command-line?

I've tried `lhhreplay` but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood the question, it is neccesary to perform a `GET` HTTP request to particular server.

The following tools may be helpful:

- `telnet`. You can connect to specified remote server via specified port, and send requests/get responses.
- `wget`. Linux command line HTTP client. Area of usage limited by protocols used for web browsing - HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, etc. Should be ok for the requested purpose.
- `curl`. Long words short, similar to the previous tools.
- `Firefox` with some addons installed, for example `Firebug`. Provides user-friendly UI for displaying network activity related to page opening.

Comment: great, can I use Firefox&Firebug command line ? I don't need to perform GET I just want page to get loaded with json and intercept this GET request to mysql.

Comment: What do you mean by "GET request to mysql"? There is no such thing AFAIK. Using Firefox with Firebug you can review all HTTP requests and responses were done to load some particular page/URL.

Comment: I gave you tools and site so you can check by yourself. Site after loading is calling mysql2json content so I need to intercept this request as URL. I repeat my question, can this be done command-line ?